# Are there many logic circuit solvers available to test / download?

Tags: digital-logic, software

All -

I have found something called "Simple Solver" located here:

http://home.roadrunner.com/~ssolver/syn.html

and you can download it here

http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Simple-Solver-Download-103308.html

My question is: Is Simple Solver the only one out there that solves digital circuits for you given inputs / outputs you want? Is there other software besides Simple Solver that will solve digital circuits?

Would appreciate all / any advise.

Comment: Most FPGA vendors (Xilinx, Altera, Lattice) have a free FPGA design tool, which includes a logic simulator. That said, I'm voting to close the question because it's basically a shopping question -- the answers are not likely to remain valid for future users as different tools are created, evolve, and die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By "solve" it appears to mean generate gates. All FPGA and ASIC synthesis tools do that. As The Photon said, this includes free tools from FPGA vendors.